# remove warning messages on build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

when i run stylecop on a file it displays warning messages along with other warning messages of other files... can we refresh the warning screen to display only stylecop warnings

Answer (score 0):

Setting the **warning level** to **0** in the build options should help.
Of course, it would be better to fix the warnings :)

The build options can be found by right clicking your project in the Solution Explorer and choosing *Properties*. Then select the *Build* tab on the left.